# Visual Studio build problem

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

We have a VS 2003 solution containing 1 vb project and several c# projects(No web projects). The problem is when i try to build the vb project either VS exits or stuck at "performing main compilation". Please help

Can not reproduce it.
Clear build doesnt work.
Sometimes problems is solved without doing anything logical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my previous experience I can say that VS2003 doesn't like too much Mixed projects (I got many strange behaviours and various crashes).

I suggest you to create 1 solution to contains your C# projects and 1 solution for VB.NET ones. Then add the necessary references browsing for them.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried "Clean" from the build menu then recompile ?